# Как отобразить html страницу в springboot посредством RestController

Tags: java, spring, rest

Разбираюсь с SpringBoot Framework, не могу понять как отобразить статическую html страницу из ресурсов, ниже мой REST контроллер.
Сама страница лежит в каталоге: myprojectname/resources/index.html
[Ссылка на мой проект.](https://dropmefiles.com/40Ryt)

```
@RestController
public class Auth {
    @GetMapping("/auth")
    public String auth() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

‌

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: чтобы отображать html страницы используйте просто Controller, а не RestController.

Answer (score 1):

Аннотация @RestController - это комбинация аннотаций @ResponseBody и @Controller. Соответственно, благодаря @ResponseBody, REST контроллеры возвращают не логическое имя страницы, а просто строку. Тебе нужно использовать просто @Controller.

Comment: Если использовать чисто `@Controller` то получаю WhitebleError. Что не хватает `@Controller` ?

Answer (score 0):

Через RestController это можно сделать вот так:

```
return new ModelAndView("index");
```